# Crash due to NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, bing-maps

I have just started to learn to integrate BingMaps into iOS Application.
I have just downloaded some sample application from http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2011/05/05/new-bing-maps-ios-sdk/ .

I got

```
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing.'**
```

I just put `[_myMapView setDelegate:self];` in viewdidload.

Please provide me the best way to overcome the issue.

And also I tried

```
dispatch_queue_t reentrantAvoidanceQueue = dispatch_queue_create("reentrantAvoidanceQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
dispatch_async(reentrantAvoidanceQueue, ^{
    [_myMapView setDelegate:self];
});
dispatch_sync(reentrantAvoidanceQueue, ^{ });
```

But same issue happens.

FYI,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00374946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01411a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0037486d +[NSException raise:format:] + 141
3   Foundation                          0x010ccb6c +[NSXMLParser setCurrentParser:] + 172
4   Foundation                          0x010cd4cd -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] + 67
5   Foundation                          0x010cd71e -[NSXMLParser parse] + 33
6   MyBingMap                           0x00108353 -[BMMapConfiguration parser:didEndElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:] + 336
7   Foundation                          0x010d046c _endElementNs + 763
8   libxml2.2.dylib                     0x007978c7 xmlParseEndTag2 + 841
9   libxml2.2.dylib                     0x00799fbf xmlParseTryOrFinish + 3601
10  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x00798fb2 xmlParseChunk + 952
11  Foundation                          0x010cd0fd -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 314
12  Foundation                          0x010cd3d8 -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 1045
13  Foundation                          0x010cd5bd -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] + 307
14  Foundation                          0x010cd71e -[NSXMLParser parse] + 33
15  MyBingMap                           0x00107bce -[BMMapConfiguration networkData:withState:withHttpStatus:withHttpHeaders:] + 224
16  MyBingMap                           0x000fe777 -[BINetworkWorkOperation _callDelegate] + 1554
17  MyBingMap                           0x000fe071 -[BINetworkWorkOperation main] + 313
18  Foundation                          0x00fb4567 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 700
19  Foundation                          0x00fb4299 -[NSOperation start] + 83
20  Foundation                          0x00fb40e3 __NSOQSchedule_f + 237
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02eb0e2f _dispatch_client_callout + 14
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02e96afc _dispatch_queue_drain + 1475
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02e963c3 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 212
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02e99067 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 466
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02e9a87e _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 45
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0321cdab _pthread_wqthread + 336
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x03220cce start_wqthread + 30
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Please provide me the best way to overcome this issue.

Comment: I removed  [_myMapView setDelegate:self]; code. I didnt handle the BMMapView at all. What I did is setting one view as BMMapView in nib file.

Comment: Still app is crashed due to NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Bing Maps iOS control. It was deprecated several months ago. In stead use the Bing Maps V7 JavaScript control inside a WebBrowser control. You end up getting a lot more features and functionality and it performs really well. Almost all apps on iOS that use Bing Maps do it this way.